# Git clone fsync error, permission denied

Tags: git

I try to clone a git repo with :  `sudo git clone https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle test`

And i have this output :

```
Cloning into 'test'...
remote: Counting objects: 24066, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (60/60), done.
remote: Total 24066 (delta 28), reused 5 (delta 2)
Receiving objects: 100% (24066/24066), 13.43 MiB | 2.11 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (11983/11983), done.
fatal: fsync error on '/vagrant/test/.git/objects/pack/tmp_idx_KWLQBb': Permission denied
fatal: index-pack failed
```

What can i do ?

Comment: why are you using `sudo`?

Comment: Don't know, it's the same with sudo or not sudo

Comment: So don't use it, because it's not an administrator operation. Also check your free disk-space.

Comment: Ok, i have 56Go of free disk space

Comment: How this folder is shared and what is your host OS?

Comment: @KrzysDan I have this same problem. It's shared over an all OSX network using afp://

Answer (score 2):

some filesystems do not support the fsync() system call, such as NFS, sshfs, ...

certain git operations like clone, push (if the remote repo is on that filesystem) etc... will fail with fsync: ... permission denied

the solution  - on linux - is "eatmydata" (apt install eatmydata)

Its a wrapper / preloaded libc overlay, which simulates fsync() calls without actually performing them.

Downside is, this slightly increases risk of damage to the repository if the filesystem goes away ( network error, power outage, stick removed, ...) during the git operation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a permission problem. Just do on the folder:

```
sudo chown -R youruser .
```

(Being **.** the folder you are when you do *git clone*)

Comment: Delete the whole folder, create it and clone again. I had no problem cloning it.

Comment: I tried doing that and I get "operation not permitted" for every file.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when the current folder was on an USB-Drive formatted in NTFS. Using a drive formatted with ext4 worked without problems.

```
$ uname -a
Linux 3.13.0-44-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 16 00:22:43 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ git --version
git version 1.9.1
```